# How to enable button depening on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem. How to enable/disable a button depending on the cell value.

In excel sheet i have 2 buttons.

What i need to do is.

If a column "L" having data

The one button enable

else

"BQ" is having data

another button needs to be enabled.
Other button will be disabled.

How to achieve it.

Please help ....
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was waiting for your reply as to what should happen if both are filled up. I have added that option in the code. Amend it to suit your needs.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CommandButton1.Enabled = False: CommandButton2.Enabled = False

    '~~> If both cols are filled up
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(12)) > 0 And _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(69)) > 0 Then
        '~~> Change the message as applicable
        MsgBox "Both Columns Cannot have data", vbInformation, "Error"
    Else
        '~~> If Col L is filled up
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(12)) > 0 _
        Then CommandButton1.Enabled = True

        '~~> If Col BQ is filled up
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(69)) > 0 _
        Then CommandButton2.Enabled = True
    End If
LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I was in offline.
Thanks a lot Siddharth. If both are having the data it should be an error. The data should contain either L or BQ only.
Thank you so much.....

Comment: modified only the button names and the column numbers as 60 and 71. It impacts anything ?

Comment: Are the button names correct? Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: When updating the column 60, "Both Columns Cannot have data", vbInformation, "Error" appearing. every update instead enabling buttons

Comment: Yes that is because both columns have data... Wait a moment... Do you by chance want to compare only the cells in that particular row or the entire column? For example L5 and BQ5, L35 and BQ35?

Comment: Can I see your file? You can upload the file in www.wikisend.com and share the link here. Let me have a look at it

Comment: Hi Siddharath I am not able to upload the file on the given site, it is blocked for me. I need to it row by row. If user updating the data in 1 row then the button enable required based on value. like wise for all the rows.

Now, when i use the above code it displaying an error message "Both columns cant have data".

Answer (score 0):

Replace CommandButton1 and CommandButton2 with whatever the names of your buttons are.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("L:L")) > 0 Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    Else
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    End If

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("BQ:BQ")) > 0 Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
        CommandButton2.Enabled = True
    Else
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    CommandButton2.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The 2nd If will enable `CommandButton1` even if there is no data in Col L and Col BQ

Comment: Nicely spotted. I'd spend some time correcting, but I'm sure your answer already does the job.

Comment: Thanks mattboy for your update... But i need to do it on row by row basis. That means if a user updating data in row 2 basing on that button enable is required.